# Output a table row as XML with Groupby another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have the following table:

```
Dept     Skills
1        200
1        250
2        150
2        200
2        250
```

and require this output:

```
Dept      XMLcolumn
1         <xcol>200></xcol><xcol>250</xcol>
2         <xcol>150></xcol><xcol>200</xcol><xcol>250</xcol>
```

I tried `FOR XML PATH` without much success:

```
select dept, skills from table for xml path('xcol'), type
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
        Dept INT,
        Skills INT
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ( 1,200),( 1,250),( 2,150),( 2,200),( 2,250)

SELECT  Dept,
        (
            SELECT  Skills xcol
            FROM    @TABLE
            WHERE   Dept = t.Dept
            FOR XML RAW(''), ELEMENTS
        )
FROM    @TABLE t
GROUP BY    Dept
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/33245)

Comment: **@astander:** Worked like charm!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT Dept,
    (SELECT '<xcol>' + CAST(Skills as nvarchar)+ '</xcol>'
       FROM tbl a
       where a.Dept=b.Dept
        FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)') XMLColumn
FROM tbl b
group by Dept
```